# How to use mongoose promises correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have been working on this piece of code in node js and the problem with it is that sometimes it works but sometimes it doesn't (I use mongoose):

```
promises.push(Quote.findOne({_id: req.params.quoteId}).then((quote) => {
        //retrive the quote's comments
        var commentPromises = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < quote.comments.length; i++){
            commentPromises.push(Comment.findOne({_id: quote.comments[i].commentId}));
        }
        Promise.all(commentPromises).then((comments) => {
            console.log(comments)
            //remove comment from it's author's list of submitted comments
            var commentRemovePromises = [];
            comments.forEach((comment) => {
                //for each comment retrive its author
                commentRemovePromises.push(User.findOne({_id: comment.author}))
            })
            Promise.all(commentRemovePromises).then((commentAuthors) =>  {
                commentAuthors.forEach((commentAuthor) => {
                    //for each author delete the comment id from his list of sumitted comments
                    for(var i = 0; i < commentAuthor.comments.length; i++){
                        if(commentAuthor.comments[i].commentId === comments[i].id){
                            var position = i;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    User.findOne({_id: commentAuthor.id}).then((commentAuthor1) => {
                        commentAuthor1.comments.splice(position, 1);
                        commentAuthor1.save();
                    })
                })
            })
            //remove comment id from all users lists' of comments that they hearted
            //remove comment id from the quote's author's list of otherUsersComments
        })
    }))

    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        //delete all comments under this quote
        Comment.find({quoteId: req.params.quoteId}).remove().then(() => {
            Quote.findOneAndRemove({_id: req.params.quoteId}).then(() => {
                res.json() 
            });
        })
    });
});
```

I usually get that comments (line 8) returns an array of [null, null etc.]. The problem seems to be that `console.log(comments)` runs before the comments array gets any values, this however doesn't make any sense because I use `Promise.all()`.
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: You should be returning those promises. `return Promise.all` etc